# ComboBox inside DataGrid in .Net compact Framework

Tags: compact-framework

I am creating Windows Mobile 6.1 application with.net compact framework  and I need to dispaly and bind combobox in datagrid.There is no functionality/Property in datagird to add comboBox inside datagrid. 
How should I do this??

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16051522/455904

Comment: Thanks for you reply Fredik.I have seen this link before but they give me different solution and I need to display comboBox anyhow.because datagrid's another cell value is changed according to combox selected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a good place to start http://www.ehartwell.com/InfoDabble/DataGrid_extensions_for_the_Compact_Framework

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/FlexGridMobileDevices/ for an extended datadrid.